# RabbitMQ not throwing error on invalid routing key

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have the following code in C#, which does not throw error if the routing key is invalid.

```
var connFactory = GetConnectionFactory();

using (var conn = connFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = conn.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.TxSelect();

        var publicationAddress = new PublicationAddress(ExchangeType.Direct, Settings.ServiceBusExchange, Settings.ServiceBusRoutingKey);

        var headers = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        headers.Add("TransactionID", transactionID);

        var basicProperties = new BasicProperties();
        basicProperties.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8.ToString();
        basicProperties.ContentType = "text/xml";
        basicProperties.Headers = headers;
        basicProperties.DeliveryMode = 2;

        var payLoad = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        channel.BasicPublish(publicationAddress, basicProperties, payLoad);
        channel.TxCommit();
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I make the code throw error if the routing key is invalid? Like when I Publish a message using RabbitMQ UI with invalid routing key, it gives a message "Message published, but not routed."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not exist the concept of "invalid routing key", since you can bind dynamically  queues to the exchanges.

Btw what you are looking for is "unroutable messages", you have to use the `mandatory` flag and implement the `ReturnListener` in the same channel, if a message does not reach any queue will be redirect to the handler.
In this in this way (the code is Java, but in c# is more or less the same):

```
 boolean isMandatory = true; // if true the message will be handled by HandlingReturnListener
        // if false the message will be dropped!

        channel.addReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {
            public void handleReturn(int replyCode, String replyText, String exchange, String routingKey, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                System.out.println(replyText + ":" + replyCode);
                System.out.println("********  UnHandled Message ***************");

            }

        });

        String myExchange = "myUnroutableExchange_";
        channel.exchangeDeclare(myExchange, "topic", false, false, null);
        channel.basicPublish(myExchange, "NO_KEY", isMandatory, null, "".getBytes());
```

Answer (score -1):

For this there is something called PublisherAcknoledgement. This will basically gives an Ack to the publisher about the status of the message. You will be able to also differentiate between whether the message has reached till Exchange or it has reached till the consumer. You just have to handle each case properly.

This is a good way to know the status of the message being delivered. You might not know if its happening because of the wrong routing key but with doing various checks you might be able to narrow down to the result.

Comment: `Publish Confirm` confirm that the message reaches the server not the queue.